# Using binary in python test in bazel

Tags: bazel

I would like to write some end-to-end tests of my C++ binary, that would provide some input file and read output from stdout and assert it's correct. I wrote a simple python test and it works fine and now I try to make it work with bazel. I added `py_test` to bazel and it builds, but I can't specify `cc_binary` in deps of that target (bazel complains). If I don't run the build command of the `cc_binary` separately, the python test won't see the binary in `bazel-bin`. How can I force to also build my `cc_binary` before running `py_test`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the binary as a data dependency.  See [the encyclopedia](http://bazel.io/docs/be/python.html#py_test.data) for details, but it would basically look something like:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "my-bin",
    srcs = ["bin.cc"],
)

py_test(
    name = "my-test",
    srcs = ["my_test.py"],
    data = [":my-bin"],
    # any other attributes you need...
)
```